# How complex can an enum get before reading lines of data from a file is better (e.g. .csv)?

Tags: java, csv, enums

I have created part of a platformer game where I have an actor class, representing instances of objects and characters, and a type enum which denotes what data each actor will have (such as speed, attack, defence, etc).
Specifying all the data of each type seems somewhat tedious with hardcoded enum definitions.
E.g.

```
PLANE("Plane", 10, 10, 2, 0),
MISSILE("Missile", 1, 0, 0, 4);
```

Would it be best to specify data in a file and read it instead?

Comment: It's more of a question about flexibility than complexity: what level of flexibility does your application require?

Comment: define 'best.' faster? less ram usage? mutability?

Answer (score 1):

My answer to that question would now be: Take a DSL for it, for instance using Kotlin (similar things are possible in Groovy).

Without going into any detail, the following can be valid Kotlin (actually working code copied from a production system):

```
buildTreats {
    category(BEVERAGE) {
        treat(id = 2, key = "bonusfood.treat.appleJuice") {
            47.kcal
            0.5 of GLASS
        }
    …
    }
    …
}
```

The advantage is that you have full code completion and compile-time checks that you just cannot have with a CSV file.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts here:

- instead of giving a "human readable" name string to your enum, you could as well @Override the toString() method to automatically return `Plane` for PLANE (easy - just lowercase everything except first letter)
- such code breaks your ability to add more features later on

There is the old [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). Basically it is saying: your code needs should be *open* in those areas where *change* is most likely to happen.

I am pretty sure: today you need 4 values, like `10, 10, 2, 0` for a Plane, as above. But in a few days, you might want to have **more** attributes. Then you have to turn to all your enum constants and update them.

In that sense, it *might* be better to give up a bit of compile time safety here; and use a Map instead. Map key could be an enum (just **listing** the different potential properties some player/item/... has). Map key would be the specific value for that strength.

If you would want to go down that route, you could then specify a **type** for each enum constant. So that you know that a map value for STRENGTH for example would be a Integer object, or something alike.

In other words: you *might* turn into the dark realms of reflection here.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of `enum` is that they are fixed in code and will not change. This provides huge benefits when coding, type checking and you can make `Map`s and `Set` of them and you can iterate across them and even switch-case with them (although that is less common now they can have their own functionality). You can even save them in a database so long as you use their names and the data still maps back correctly even when the enum list changes.

As such, I would not abandon them , I would probably add a new one called perhaps "OTHERS" which can somehow provide any new ones that are experimental etc.

If your core issue is with the tediousness of maintaining the parameters then by all means read that data in from configuration using a static initialiser.